# Dividir colunas sem separador Pandas

Tags: pandas, split, columns

Existe algum método em pandas para divisão de colunas sem separador? seria uma espécie de ext.texto do excel.

Tenho uma base com uma coluna de 20 caracteres, porém, só preciso do intervalo entre o 11 e 14.

ex. 22222222222**ABXF**22222

Obs. não há um padrão entre o miolo que eu necessito.

Comment: Incremente sua pergunta com maneiras que já tentou resolver seu problema

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Utilizando o que o colega falou acima, podemos simplificar tambem e colocar mais um modo de excluir esses números indesejados,

***IN***

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({"col": ["22222222222ABXF22222", "33333333333BCYG33333"]})
>>> df['col'].replace(regex=True,inplace=True,to_replace=r'2|3',value=r'')
>>> df
```

***OUT***

```
col
0   ABXF
1   BCYG
```

Dentro do TO_REPLACE você consegue passar varios parametros e no VALUE você vai conseguir escolher o que substituir no lugar da variavel que esta tirando.

Answer (score 1):

Duas opções:

Use str e colchetes:

```
df['new'] = df['col'].str[11:15]
```

Ou str.slice:

```
df['new'] = df['col'].str.slice(11, 15)
```

**Exemplo**

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({"col": ["22222222222ABXF22222", "33333333333BCYG33333"]})
>>> df
                    col
0  22222222222ABXF22222
1  33333333333BCYG33333

>>> df['new'] = df['col'].str[11:15]
>>> df
                    col   new
0  22222222222ABXF22222  ABXF
1  33333333333BCYG33333  BCYG
>>>
```

Nota: você pode atribuir o resultado para a própria coluna ("col") e sobrescrever o que vc tinha anteriormente

Espero que ajude

Comment: Muito Obrigado! foi espetacular!

Comment: @EduardoGarciadeOliveira, caso ache pertinente, marque a resposta como solução e dê um upvote. Aproveite para ler [este post](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/605/como-dizer-obrigado-em-respostas)

Comment: Eu tentei, mas como sou novo o site retorna que foi computado, mas não aparece como seta verde.